# When is MPI_wait necessary with non-blocking calls?

Tags: c, mpi, hpc

I'm a little bit confused about when I should call MPI_Wait (or other variants such as: MPI_Waitall, MPII_Waitsome, etc). Consider the following situations: (Note: pseudo code)

Case (1)

```
MPI_Isend (send_buffer, send_req);    
// Do local work
MPI_Probe (recv_msg);
MPI_Irecv (recv_buffer, recv_req);
// wait for msgs to finish
MPI_Wait (recv_req);   // <--- Is this needed?
MPI_Wait (send_req);   // <--- How about this?
```

So my confusion stems from `MPI_Probe` in this case. Since this is a blocking call, wouldn't that essentially mean it blocks the caller until message is received? If this is the case, then I think MPI_Waits are unnecessary here.

How about the following case?

Case (2)

```
MPI_Isend (send_buffer, send_req);    
// Do local work
MPI_Probe (recv_msg);
MPI_Recv (recv_buffer);
// wait for msgs to finish
MPI_Wait (send_req);   // <--- Is this necessary?
```

Similar to the first case but `MPI_Irecv` is replaced with its blocking version. In this case, the message is definitely received by the time `MPI_Wait` is called which means `MPI_Isend` must have been finished ...

Also as a separate question, what do we mean when we say `MPI_Probe` is blocking? Does it block until all of the message is received by the process or does it only block until "meta-data" (such as msg size, sender rank, etc) is received? In other words is `MPI_Probe` + `MPI_Irecv` any better than `MPI_Probe` + `MPI_Recv` ?

Comment: Since this question was already answered on SciComp (http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/when-is-mpi-wait-necessary-for-non-blocking-calls), you should close this question. There's no need for duplicate answers.

Comment: Already asked here: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8308/when-is-mpi-wait-necessary-for-non-blocking-calls

Answer (score 0):

Only when you wants to receives data asynchronously, you need to use the "MPI_Wait" function or MPI_Waitall if you initiated various asynchronous read. The problem is that MPI_Wait is a blocking call. If you want to have non-blocking you should use MPI_Test to check the completion of your function.

In your case, the MPI_Probe will block until a message is received. So I would say that your call to MPI_Probe is not necessary in your case.